# VBA code for matching the string and copying it

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that matches the string and copies it to the next sheet. But when i make changes so that it pastes the value in the same sheet but different column it doesn't work. I am trying to match the array in the red part and copying it into the C column

[image: Sample of The xlsx]

```
Option Explicit
Sub SearchForString()
 Dim a As Long, arr As Variant, fnd As Range, cpy As Range, addr As 
 String
 On Error GoTo Err_Execute
  'populate the array for the outer loop
  arr = Array("trigger")
  With Worksheets("test")
   'outer loop through the array
   For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
       'locate first instance
       Set fnd = .Columns("A").Find(what:=arr(a), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
       If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
          'record address of first find
           addr = fnd.Address
           'seed the cpy range object
           If cpy Is Nothing Then Set cpy = fnd.EntireRow
           Do
               'build union
               Set cpy = Union(cpy, fnd.EntireRow)
               'look for another
               Set fnd = .Columns("A").FindNext(after:=fnd)
           'keep finding new matches until it loops back to the first
           Loop Until fnd.Address = addr
       End If
   Next a
  End With
    With Worksheets("test")
    'one stop copy & paste operation
   cpy.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 End With

  MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

  Exit Sub
 End Sub
```

Comment: Don't copy `entirerow`.

Comment: @SJR its working fine when i set the worksheet to a new worksheet.

Comment: @SJR i want to copy thing to happen in the same sheet but in different column

Comment: Did you understand my comment? `Set cpy = fnd.EntireRow` Why entirerow? You can't move an entire row 2 columns to the right. It won't fit.

Comment: @SJR okay i understand now..thanks for being patient with me. what changes do you suggest?

Comment: Well if you just want to copy the found cell just use `fnd` in place of `fnd.EntireRow` throughout.

Comment: @SJR let me try and get back to you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193386/discussion-between-j-doe-and-sjr).